# Python: merging pandas data frames results in only NaN in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, bigdata

I am currently working on a Big Data project requiring the merger of a number of files into a single table that can be analyzed through SAS. The majority of work is completed with the final fact tables needing to be added to the final output.

I have hit a snag when attempting to combine a fact table to the final output. In this csv file that has been loaded to its own dataframe the following columns are present.

```
table name: POP
year | Borough | Population
```

within the dataset on which they are to be enjoined these fields also exist along with around 26 others. When first attempted to merge through the following line:

```
#Output = pd.merge(Output, POP, on=['year', 'Borough'], how='outer')
```

the following error was returned

> ValueError: You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns. If
>   you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

i understood this to simply be a data type mismatch and so added the following line ahead of the merge command:

```
POP['year'] = POP['year'].astype(object)
```

doing so allows for ""successfull"" execution of the program, however, the output file has the population column, but it is filled with NaN when it should have the appropriate population for each row where a combination of "year" and "borough" match that found in the POP table.

any help would be greatly appreciated and i provide below a fuller excerpt of the code for those who find that easier to parse:

```
import pandas as pd


#
# Add Population Data
#

#rename columns for easier joining
POP.rename(columns={"Area name":"Borough"}, inplace=True)
POP.rename(columns={"Persons":"Population"}, inplace=True)
POP.rename(columns={"Year":"year"}, inplace=True)

#convert type of output column to allow join
POP['year'] = POP['year'].astype(object)


#add to output file
Output = pd.merge(Output, POP, on=['year', 'Borough'], how='outer')
```

Additionally find below some information about the data types and shape of the items and tables involved in case it is of use:

```
> Output table info
> 
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> Int64Index: 34241 entries, 0 to
> 38179 Data columns (total 2 columns): year       34241 non-null object
> Borough    34241 non-null object dtypes: object(2) memory usage:
> 535.0+ KB None table shape: (34241, 36)
> ----------
> 
> POP table info <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> RangeIndex: 357
> entries, 0 to 356 Data columns (total 3 columns): year          357
> non-null object Borough       357 non-null object Population    357
> non-null object dtypes: object(3) memory usage: 4.2+ KB None table
> shape: (357, 3)
```

finally, my apologies if any of this is asked or presented incorrectly, I'm relatively new to python and its my first time using stack as a contributor

EDITS:

(1)

as requested here is samples from the data:

this is the Output Dataframe

```
[357 rows x 3 columns]
                  Borough       Date  totalIncidents  Calculated Mean Closure  \
0                  Camden 2013-11-06             2.0                    613.5   
1  Kensington and Chelsea 2013-11-06             NaN                      NaN   
2             Westminster 2013-11-06             1.0                    113.0   

   PM2.5 (ug/m3)  PM10 (ug/m3) (R)  SO2 (ug/m3) (R)  CO (mg m-3) (R)  \
0           9.55            16.200              5.3              NaN   
1          10.65            21.125              1.7              0.2   
2          19.90            30.600              NaN              0.7   

   NO (ug/m3) (R)  NO2 (ug/m3) (R)  O3 (ug/m3) (R)  Bus Stops  \
0      135.866670        82.033333            24.4      447.0   
1       80.360000        65.680000            29.3      270.0   
2      171.033333       109.000000            21.3      489.0   

   Cycle Parking Points  \
0                  67.0   
1                  27.0   
2                  45.0   

   Average Public Transport Access Index 2015 (AvPTAI2015)  \
0                                          24.316782         
1                                          23.262691         
2                                          39.750796         

  Public Transport Accessibility Levels (PTAL) Catagorisation  \
0                                                  5            
1                                                  5            
2                                                 6a            

   Underground Stations in Borough  \
0                             16.0   
1                             12.0   
2                             31.0   

  PM2.5 Daily Air Quality Index(DAQI) classification  \
0                                                Low   
1                                                Low   
2                                                Low   

   PM2.5 Above WHO 24hr mean Guidline  PM10 Above WHO 24hr mean Guidline  \
0                                 0.0                                0.0   
1                                 0.0                                0.0   
2                                 0.0                                0.0   

   O3 Above WHO 8hr mean Guidline*  NO2 Above WHO 1hr mean Guidline*  \
0                              1.0                               1.0   
1                              1.0                               1.0   
2                              1.0                               1.0   

   SO2 Above WHO 24hr mean Guidline  SO2 Above EU 24hr mean Allowence  \
0                               0.0                               0.0   
1                               0.0                               0.0   
2                               0.0                               0.0   

   NO2 Above EU 24hr mean Allowence  CO Above EU 8hr mean Allowence  \
0                               1.0                             0.0   
1                               1.0                             0.0   
2                               1.0                             0.0   

   O3 Above EU 8hr mean Allowence  year  NO2 Year Mean (ug/m3)  \
0                             0.0  2013              50.003618   
1                             0.0  2013              50.003618   
2                             0.0  2013              50.003618   

   PM2.5 Year Mean (ug/m3)  PM10 Year Mean (ug/m3)  \
0                15.339228               24.530299   
1                15.339228               24.530299   
2                15.339228               24.530299   

   NO2 Above WHO Annual mean Guidline  NO2 Above EU Annual mean Allowence  \
0                                 0.0                                 1.0   
1                                 0.0                                 1.0   
2                                 0.0                                 1.0   

   PM2.5 Above EU Annual mean Allowence  PM10 Above EU Annual mean Allowence  \
0                                   0.0                                  0.0   
1                                   0.0                                  0.0   
2                                   0.0                                  0.0   

  Number of Bicycle Hires (All Boroughs)  
0                                 18,431  
1                                 18,431  
2                                 18,431
```

here is the Population dataframe

```
   year               Borough Population
0  2010  Barking and Dagenham   182,838 
1  2011  Barking and Dagenham   187,029 
2  2012  Barking and Dagenham   190,560
```

edit(2):
so this seems that it was a date type issue but im still not entirely sure why as i had attempted recasting the datatypes. However, the solution that finall got me going was to save the output dataframe as a csv and reload it into the programme, from there the merge started working again.

Comment: could you please provide a small piece of example data? maybe use `head` on the dataframes before concatenation

Comment: Sure, just added a .head(3)  sameple it to the original question

Comment: Look at your source, the data might have trailing spaces which prevent them from merging onto the right record.

Comment: Thanks, I did check that but it seems it was ok. I just managed to fix the issue however. Im not 100% sure what the issue was but i decided to export the DF as csv and reload it, this seem to resolve the type conflict and allow the tables to be merged again. I'm not 100% sure why this would be the case because i attempted recasting the data types previously but for now it works all be it somewhat messily, thankfully only i will be needing that output.